# tensorflow2.1 InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [0] [Op:Assert] name: EagerVariableNameReuse

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained my custom model and used tensorflow 2.1. When I run the code I'm getting the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [0] [Op:Assert] name:
>   EagerVariableNameReuse

Here is the line which showing the error:

```
self.train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy('train_accuracy')
```

What does this error mean, thanks in advance.

Comment: Since your code was working yesterday and not working today, are you sure that you are running your whole Jupyter code? Cuz, runnning some part of your code twice in Jupyter might give an error. So, please try to run your whole code if you are using Jupyter

Comment: I faced the same issue: i triggerd this error if i ran my script on tf 2.0 GPU and did not set the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES explicit to -1 (at this time GPU was already in occupied by another training script). Error dissapeard when i ran it on tf2.3 CPU

Answer (score 4):

Providing the solution here even though it is present in Github, for the benefit of the Stackoverflow Community.

Whenever we are trying to run two python programs that use Tensorflow at the same time triggers this error. Please close other python session using Tensorflow will resolve this issue.

For more information please refer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38518).

Comment: I have the same issue but running `nvidia-smi` returns `No running processes found`. So, in my case, the issue seems not to be linked to two programs using Tensorflow at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, with the following configuration:

- Windows 10
- GPU on GE Force MX130 with driver 451.67
- CUDA 10.1
- cuDNN 7.6
- TensorFlow 2.3.0

I solved it by downgrading from TensorFlow 2.3.0 to TensorFlow 2.2.0 (as also mentioned [here on Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38518#issuecomment-669878400)).

Comment: Same situation here and the downgrade worked for me as well. Just as a reminder, remember to downgrade tensorflow-gpu (pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0)

Comment: As per January 2020, I discovered that it is possible to install the above configuration with TensorFlow 2.3.0 in `conda`, if version 2.1.0 is first installed with `conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.1.0 cudatoolkit=10.1` (with Python 3.7, there is no other way) and then upgraded to version 2.3.0 with `conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.3.0 cudatoolkit=10.1` (strangely enough, direct installation of version 2.3.0 fails to detect CUDA). Performances wrt version 2.2.0 installed with pip seems to be minimally better.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the environment variable `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH` to true seems to make this issue disapper:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = "true"
```

Not sure why though.

Comment: It does not fix the problem for me.

Comment: It does not fix the problem for me, either

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out that the error is caused in `TensorFlow 2.3.0`, and downgrading to `2.2.0` worked perfectly.

try:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Try not to use LSTM and... in the model and for example use only Dense and try again. I solved the problem by placing a layer of Flatten between the Dense layer and the LSTM!
In general, there may be a bug in the structure of your model.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).