# TensorFlow 2.3 GPU - InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [0] [Op:Assert] name: EagerVariableNameReuse

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.x

**Environment:**

Windows 8.1 64 bit
Python 3.7.7 64 bit
TensorFlow 2.3
Keras 2.4

CUDA: 10.1
CuDNN: 7

**Error** : `InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [0] [Op:Assert] name: EagerVariableNameReuse`.

**Problem** : Above error at a simple statement `model = Sequential()` at GPU execution

But if I run the script without GPU (not setting CUDA/CuDnn environment variables it works as expected.

So effectively, I have a GPU but can't use with TensorFlow(2.3)

Can someone help?

Comment: Please provide the exact code you want to run

Comment: def get_model(n_inputs=800, n_outputs=200):
 

 model = keras.Sequential()
 
 model.add(BatchNormalization())
 model.add(Dense(512, input_dim=n_inputs,  activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dropout(0.2))
 
 
 model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=n_inputs,  activation='relu'))
 
 
 model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid'))
 
 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
 return model

model = get_model()

Comment: @user2533922, Does this [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38518#issuecomment-674339731) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200676/) answer your query?

Comment: @TFer2 . None of these is a solution. I know it will work if I downgrade TF to 2.2..i have been using GPU till I upgraded to TF 2.3

Comment: I could not able to replicate your error with Google Colab `TF 2.3` and `Cuda 10.1` using `Sequential Model`. Please can you clear all python sessions and trying again.

Comment: @TFer2 ..I am on my local machine not on Colab...I was ok till I upgraded to TF 2.3..will try again sometime in the coming days..

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen, this issue comes up for the following deadly combination.

- Windows OS
- TensorFlow 2.3.x

I've been struggling to solve this for quite sometime and only figured it out recently.

#### Easiest fix

Easiest solution would be to go for TensorFlow 2.4.0rcx. It is still in pre-release. But haven't given me the aforementioned issue. So,

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.4.0rc0
```

#### Solution if you want to stay with TF 2.3.x

If you're really adamant about using TensorFlow 2.3.x the only solutions seem to be,

- Trying a Linux based OS (Ubuntu)
- Compiling TensorFlow from source (According to [this helpful](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41855#issuecomment-723420047) comment)

Comment: @thushv89..Thank you...2.4 will require upgrade to CuDA 11. I just downgraded TF to 2.2.1 as before and everything worked as before and expected.. Will try 2.4 when it releases..